# Problems updating password in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hi i'm a ruby newbie and i'm having problems updating user password, how can i validate the old password with the current password? in order to change it, the password field and password_confirmation field don't validate!...This is my users_controller code:...Also i have some errors in `sign_in (current_user,:bypass=>true)` while trying to keep the user signed in when the password is changed

```
def edit
@user=User.find(params[:id])
@title="Editar Informacion"
end

def update
@user=User.find(params[:id])

if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  sign_in(current_user, :bypass => true)
  flash[:success]="Profile updated"
  redirect_to edit_user_path(current_user)
else
  @title="Edit user" 
  render 'edit'
end
end
```

my user model:

```
attr_accessor :password
attr_accessible :name,:email,:lastname,:password,:password_confirmation

email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

validates :name,:presence=>true,
              :length=>{:maximum=>50}

validates :lastname,:presence=>true,
                  :length=>{:maximum=>50}

validates :email,:presence=>true,
               :format=>{:with => email_regex},
               :uniqueness=> {:case_sensitive=>false}

validates :password,:presence=>true,
                  :confirmation=>true,
                  :length=>{:within=>6..40},
                  :on=>:create

before_save :encrypt_password

def has_password?(submitted_password)
encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
end

def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
user = find_by_email(email)
return nil  if user.nil?
return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
end
```

And my edit view:

```
<%=form_for @user do |c| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => c.object %>  
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="field">
            <%=c.label :old_password,"Contraseña anterior"%><br />
            <%=c.password_field :old_password%>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="field">
            <%=c.label :password, "Contraseña"%><br />
            <%=c.password_field :password%>         
    </td>
    <td class="actions" rowspan="3">
            <%=c.submit "Guardar Cambios"%>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="field">
            <%=c.label :password_confirmation,"Confirmar Contraseña"%>          <br />
            <%=c.password_field :password_confirmation%>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<%end%>
```

Thanks!

This error appears:

```
NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

i guess i'm not validating right the `:old_password` with the current password...:S

Answer (score 0):

in order to validate password should not be equal try this:

```
  validates :password_should_be_different
  def password_should_be_different
     if read_attribute(:password) == password
        errors.add :password, "is similar!"
     end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add :old_password and :password_confirmation to attr_accessor, and :old_password to attr_accessible in your model.  It should look like this:

```
attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation, :old_password
attr_accessible :name,:email,:lastname,:password,:password_confirmation, :old_password
```

If you don't define the properties (using attr_accessor) and make them available for mass-assignment (using attr_accessible), they won't be passed and your validation will fail.